# How different computers know which signed integers representation was used by each other

Tags: bit-manipulation, byte, signed, twos-complement, internal-representation

How different computers know which signed integers representation was used by each other?

For example, if I send two's complement method encoded inetegers via network, how does clients know that it was two's complement method instead of, for example, one's complement or signed magnitude?

Comment: They wouldn't. So you put it in the specification of the communication protocol.

Comment: As an example of what @harold was saying, the [unoffical quake network specs](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake/QDP/qnp.html) say: "All numbers are in big-endian order unless otherwise stated."

Comment: @Alex Taylor But I'm talking about the signed integers representation, not BE / LE

Comment: And what harold said is still true - it's agreed to in the communications protocol.